# STM32F4 Pull-Up Resistors' Value

Tags: stm32, arm, pullup, pulldown

I am working with an STM32F4 discovery board. I need to know the right value of the pull up resistors on the GPIO port.

All there is on the datasheet is "weak pull-up":

[image: page 277 of the stm32f407 datasheet]

Comment: If you need to design to a precise value,  and part count doesn't matter, you might consider disabling the pullup and providing your own.

Comment: @werberbang Unless you only are doing tests you can use internal pulls, otherwise, I recommend to use externall pullups or pulldowns and disable internal pulls. Its better to take control of value externally and not stress MCU.

Answer (score 11):

From the STM32F405/7 datasheet

[image: R_PU and R_PD table]

Since you didn't say what processor it uses, I guessed.