# SD FIFO has no data available when mounting with FATFS

Tags: microcontroller, stm32, c, embedded, sd

#### Issue

I'm attempting to mount an SD card to my STM32F407 with Elm Chan's FATFS using SDIO and `f_mount` returns `FR_DISK_ERR`.

The following sequence of functions is called from there:

`mount_volume()` > `check_fs()` >  `move_window()` > `disk_read()`

Ultimately, my error resides in `disk_read`, more specifically where the `SDIO_STA_RXDAVL` bit of `SDIO->STA` never gets raised, meaning there is no data avaialbe in the FIFO to be read, as commented below:

```c
cmd = (count > 1) ? 18 : 17;
t = msTicks;
rd = 0;

SDIO->DCTRL = ((0b1001 << 4) | SDIO_DCTRL_DTDIR);
SDIO->DLEN = (512 * count);
SDIO->DTIMER = (400000);

sta = 0;
if (!send_cmd(cmd, sector, RESP_SHORT, &resp) || (resp & 0xc0580000))   /*!MOD REG?*/
    return RES_ERROR;
SDIO->ICR = (0xFF);
SDIO->DCTRL |= (SDIO_DCTRL_SDIOEN   |
                SDIO_DCTRL_RWSTART  |
                SDIO_DCTRL_DTDIR    |
                SDIO_DCTRL_DTEN
               );

while (elapsed(t) < 1000) {

    sta = SDIO->STA;

    if (sta & (SDIO_STA_DTIMEOUT | SDIO_STA_RXOVERR | SDIO_STA_STBITERR)) {
        err("%s SDIO_STA: 0x%08X\n", __func__, (uint)sta);
        break;
    }

    if (sta & SDIO_STA_RXFIFOE)
        continue;

    if (rd == 0 && !(sta & SDIO_STA_RXDAVL))
        continue;      //<<---No data available, so can't get to FIFO

    data = SDIO->FIFO; //<<---Never gets here

    buf[rd++] = data;
    buf[rd++] = data >> 8;
    buf[rd++] = data >> 16;
    buf[rd++] = data >> 24;

    if (rd == 512 * count)
        break;
}

if (rd < 512 * count || cmd == 18)
    send_cmd(12, 0, RESP_SHORT, &resp);

return SDIO->DCOUNT ? RES_ERROR : RES_OK; //<<---Returns ERROR
```

I think my SD cards are responding alright, especially since the code returns what kind of SD it is (*SD2*) and the OCR (`0x0080FFC0`). I also checked CLK and CMD with the scope and they seem to be alright. There is no activity in any of the D[0:3] lines, though.

Why am I getting stuck?

---

#### Setup

- Board: [STM32F407ZGT6](https://github.com/mcauser/BLACK_F407ZG)
- SD cards: MicroSD [32GB HCI and 256GB XCI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WTqhk.jpg) + [4GB HC](https://www.megatronico.com.br/wp-content/uploads/2016/06/microSD_SDHC_Class4_4GB.png)
- Formats: FAT32, exFAT and exFAT
- FATFS library: [Elm Chan](http://elm-chan.org/fsw/ff/00index_e.html)
- Low Level handler: [Aurelio Colosimo](https://github.com/colosimo/fatfs-stm32/blob/master/source/diskio_stm32f4xx.c)
- Initialization @ 400kHz and Read/Write @ 4MHz
- Circuit for MicroSD (10k Ohms):
  [image: Micro SD to SD adapter circuit]

Comment: Is there a reason you are not using the driver stack provided by ST? It basically  includes FATFS.

Comment: You mean the HAL library @Justme ? If so, project requires bare-metal

Comment: If so, maybe it also requires re-inventing the wheel? The HAL exists so you can use it or use it as an example for your own code.

Comment: @Justme I mean, I'm not re-inventing the wheel necessarely. I'm using the FATFS library and Aurelio's code. Also, I know that HAL uses Elm's implementation of the FATFS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My problem was with the hardware. Although I cannot put a finger on what was the problem, I'll guess that the SD adapter was broken or had a weird pinout. Also, having only the internal GPIOs pull-ups ([30k to 50k Ohms](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/205666/stm32f4-pull-up-resistors-value)) was enough and I didn’t need the physical resistors I was adding to the circuit.

Moreover, my breaking points were generating weird results since the SD is a microprocessor itself. Therefore, every breakpoint would influence clocks and couters from the SD and the were messing up my debugging. Once I got them out of the way, the response came out positive using the embedded SD slot that came with my board.

Another problem that I found was that only the FAT32 card was accepted. ExFAT cards did not get recognized, always returning `FR_NO_FILESYSTEM`. Below the output of all my testing conditions:

| Card Type | Circuit Type | `GPIO_PUPDR` | Response |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| FAT32 | Embedded Circuit | Pull-Up | `FR_OK` |
| FAT32 | Embedded Circuit | *Pull-No | `FR_NOT_READY` |
| FAT32 | *SD Adapter Circuit | Any | `FR_DISK_ERR` |
| *ExFAT | Embedded Circuit | Any | `FR_NO_FILESYSTEM` |

<sub>* The main factors that caused errors on each combination</sub>